# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{s_1+s_2+s_3\cdots+s_n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

If a sequence is defined as $a_k=(-1)^{k-1}$ and $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$ Then Find $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{s_1+s_2+s_3\cdots+s_n}{n}$$

My try:
we have $$s_n=\frac{n+1}{2} $$ when $n$ is Odd and $$s_n=0$$ when $n$ is Even

So if we define new sequence $b_n$ as:
$$b_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{n}s_r$$

We have:

If $n=2p-1$ Then:

$$b_{2p-1}=\frac{1}{2p-1}\left(1+2+3+\cdots+p\right)=\frac{p(p+1)}{2(2p-1)}=\frac{(n+1)(n+3)}{8n}$$

Now If $n=2p$

We have:
$$b_{2p}=\frac{p(p+1)}{4p}=\frac{n(n+2)}{8n}$$

Now how to find $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n$

Comment: You had a mistake while finding the value of $s_n$ for odd $n$, it should be $1$ rather than $\frac{n+1}2$.

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n= \infty$ because the power of denominator is greate that the power of numerator.